# ReactJS VS Error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, reactjs

I started learning REACT. For starters I set up a local development environment and used sublime text as editor and started building small components. Now I want to move onto ASP.net MVC

I followed [this](https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial_aspnet4.html) tutorial till "Your First Component" but I got this error when I run the project

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I searched this error and entered these

```
type="text/babel"
type="text/jsx"
```

error gone but nothing displayed

What's this error and how can this be resolved?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: what version of `visual studio`?

Comment: VS2017....and I didn't code anything. Just followed the tutorial and copy paste everything.

Answer (score 0):

my bad.... I install the wrong dependency(React.AspNet) from the NuGet Packages.
I created the project again to ensure the problem wasn't from my side but (sigh)
then I install React.Web.Mvc4 and it worked